# heroku - get app IP to whitelist queries

Tags: python, mysql, heroku

I've pushed my first app to heroku and everything looks good except for an issue w/ MySQL.

I'm pushing/pulling a remote server that asks me to whitelist specific ip addresses. I can't find the ip address for the heroku app I've deployed so all of the queries return errors.

Any thoughts on the best way to get that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only way I was able to get the ip was to add

```
try:
    app()

except:
    except Exception,e:
        print e
```

and then check the server logs using  `heroku logs --tail`. It spit out that the IP I was using wasn't valid for queries to the db

Answer (score 0):

Heroku dynos are ephemeral. Even if you manually figure out your dyno's IP, it's going to change frequently.  IP whitelisting isn't a viable scheme for securing connections between Heroku apps and other services.  You should use TLS.